# How do i conjugate 공부하다?

Tags: grammar, verb, conjugation

I am learning Korean and am practicing verb conjugation.

I decided to write **"I study a book"**.

Following the conjugation for "하다" verbs, i wrote:

> 나는 책을 공부해.

But when i checked a translation for "i study a book", it said:

> 나는 책을 공부한다.

I am confused about why there's a ㄴ with the 하, and why 다 is added at the end?

Comment: pretty sure you mean "study" as in 공부한다 - mind if i edit your question before i answer it?

Comment: I have personally experienced that men are more likely to sound gruff and say "내가 한다" - _I'm doing it_ - whereas it seems like females use 해체 and sound more smooth and light "내가 해" - _I'm doing it_ - but that's pure opinion - I asked two natives and one agreed and the other didn't ㅎㅎㅎ

Comment: Koreans don't use the term 공부하다 for the way you used "studying".... They use 살피다(search) or 연구하다(research) etc.

Comment: 나는 책을 공부한다. is technically correct, but is something you you would use if you were writing an article, not in a normal face to face conversation. 나는 책을 공부해., 나는 책을 공부해요., 나는 책을 공부합니다 are all fine.

Answer (score 2):

Korean has lots of different [speech levels, as described in this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_speech_levels).

When you said

> 나는 책을 공부해.

That's fine - it's the kind of thing you could say to a friend. That was using the '**Hae-che' (해체)** style.

The translation you found...

> 나는 책을 공부한다.

Is also fine, but using the **'Haera-che' (해라체)** style. As described in the wiki page, you often see it in books, but it's perhaps not one of the most common styles used when actually talking to people  - at least for action verbs.

WEBjuju's answer has a good description of the difference between action and descriptive verbs in this style; From my experience, using descriptive verbs in the 'Haera-che' style is more common than using action verbs in this style.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you mean

> 공부한다  *to study*

so the "dictionary form" is `공부하다`.  from there it can be conjugated many many different ways, but let me focus a minute just on why the ㄴ다 was added.

Verbs are broken down into two main categories, as shown by the headers below.

### Action Verbs

The main conjugation into an informal, lacking polite form version adds ㄴ or 는 depending if the final sound is a vowel or not.  Like this:

`Dictionary form (minus 다)` + `ㄴ/는다`

In the case of `공부하 +` we must use the ㄴ by itself.  If you were to conjugate the dictionary form of "to eat", the final sound is a consonant, so 는 is used instead.

> 먹다 (dictionary form) = 먹는다

### Descriptive Verbs

The main conjugation *of a descriptive verb* into an informal, lacking polite form version adds...nothing.  Like this:

`Dictionary form`

So in the case of `예쁘다` - it can just be used as is, straight out of the dictionary:

> 예쁘다 (dictionary form) = 예쁘다

---

Other conjugation examples of polite forms include:

### 공부하다 (dictionary form)

- 공부하세요? *Are you studying? (Do you study?)*
- 공부해요. *I'm studying. (I study.)*
- 공부하십니까? *Are you studying? (Do you study?)*
- 공부합니다. *I'm studying. (I study.)*

### 예쁘다

- 예뻐요? *Is it pretty? (Am I pretty? Is she pretty? etc)*
- 예뻐요. *It is/she is/he is/I am/you are pretty.*
- 예쁩니까? *Is it pretty? (Am I pretty? Is she pretty? etc)*
- 예쁩니다. *It is/she is/he is/I am/you are pretty.*

---

In conclusion

> 나는 책을 공부한다

is grammatically correct (and maybe more natural) and

> 나는 책을 공부해

is grammatically correct (but probably needs the 요 to be natural...depending on context and emotion).

Also...you can study the book, but "read" the book will trump the study in a frequency contest:

> 나는 책을 읽는다 (읽다 dictionary form of "to read").